# Get Bounce effect with onOverScrolled in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an app that needs to get a bounce effect when I scroll. I was told I needed to use the onOverScrolled() method. I want to know hot to use it and where. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

**Bounce Animation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/bounce_interpolator" >

<scale
   android:duration="600"
   android:fromXScale="1"
   android:fromYScale="0.5"
   android:pivotX="50%"
   android:pivotY="0%"
   android:toXScale="1.0"
   android:toYScale="1.0" />

<alpha
   android:duration="600"
   android:fromAlpha="0.0"
   android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

**Adapter Code**

```
public class Adapter_Event_Profile extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private int lastPosition = -1;

public Adapter_Event_Profile(Context _context) {
    mContext = _context;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.raw_event_profile, parent, false);
    return new ProfileEventHolder(v);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    setAnimation(((ProfileEventHolder) holder).cardView, position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 15;
}

public class ProfileEventHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public CardView cardView;

    public ProfileEventHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    }
}

private void setAnimation(View viewToAnimate, int position) {
    // If the bound view wasn't previously displayed on screen, it's animated
    if (position > lastPosition) {
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.bounce_animation);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;
    }
  }
}
```

**RecyclerView Item**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/cardView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/scale_5dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="@dimen/scale_10dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivUserImage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/scale_80dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/scale_80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/user" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/scale_15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/scale_15dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/Lets_party"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
            android:text="@string/creat"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/scale_5dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_access_time"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@string/datetime"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

      </LinearLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

When you scroll your RecyclerView then Bounce Animation is happening.

Comment: How do I call that Bounce Animation in a ScrollView?

Comment: Can you put code more specific? What is the cardView?

Comment: CardView is RecyclerView Item. Here we have created Custom Adapter for RecyclerView

Comment: You also have a class CardView you are not showing. Can you please share all the code?

Comment: And also you have a ReciclerView class